# Confused with CKEditor toolbar definition

Tags: ckeditor, toolbar

All,

From CKEditor's developer guide(http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Toolbar), you can see there are two ways to define a toolbar:

method 1: config.toolbar_Full =
[
    { name: 'document', items : [ 'Source','-','Save','NewPage','DocProps','Preview','Print','-','Templates' ] },
....
];

method 2: config.toolbar_Full =
[
    ['Bold', 'Italic', '-', 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Link', 'Unlink','-','About']....
];

What's the difference between them? is the method 2 used in earlier version so that they have to support for backward compatibility?

another question:

config.toolbar properties, from the doc, it can be a string like config.toolbar="Full" or an array like: 
`config.toolbar =
[
    [ 'Source', '-', 'Bold', 'Italic' ]
];`

Don't you think it's kind of confusion?

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge

Method 1: has naming of the group while the second method contains only the itmes used in method 1.

Config.toolbar can be either a name of the settings or the array of the group settings.